# ERROR: too long label (226 chars). fsck

Tags: fsck

I did an fsck on exFAT, but it ends up with 19 files that can't be fix.. label too long..
I want to fix it manually, but since it didnt' report where are the files and which files are they.. how can i find them to fix it manually ?

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/sdd1 -p
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
exfatfsck 1.3.0
Checking file system on /dev/sdd1.
File system version           1.0
Sector size                 512 bytes
Cluster size                  1 MB
Volume size                5589 GB
Used space                 2624 GB
Available space            2965 GB
ERROR: too long label (226 chars).
ERROR: too long label (226 chars).
Totally 19866 directories and 224471 files.
File system checking finished. ERRORS FOUND: 19, FIXED: 0.
```

Is there any command or log to make them spit out the unfixed files ?

Thx

Comment: Maybe `-V` that produces verbose output would be helpful.

Comment: sudo fsck /dev/sdd1 -p -V does not yield any more verbose as without -V

Comment: It is weird isn't it ? a fsck scan without log ?  How is that possible that scanned with error, but no report on what are the error files ? Unbelievable.